# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException Smack

Tags: java, servlets, classnotfoundexception, openfire, smack

Smack is not working with the servlet. However, it works perfectly fine when I copy-paste my code and run it as a desktop application. 
The error occurs at ChatServer.java:42
Here's my code:

Servlet (ChatServer.java):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ChatServer
 */
@WebServlet("/ChatServer")
public class ChatServer extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public ChatServer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String jid =  request.getParameter("jid");
            String pword = request.getParameter("pword");
            Connection.register(jid, pword, "192.168.1.75", "5222");
        }


    }
```

Connection Class (Connection.java):

```
import java.util.Collection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.ConnectionConfiguration;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.RosterEntry;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException.NotConnectedException;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.packet.Presence;
import org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection;



public class Connection{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    static XMPPConnection connection;

    public static void register(String username, String password, String host, String port){
        //  username += "@" + host;
        String service = host;
        ConnectionConfiguration connConfig =
                new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port), service);
        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(connConfig);
        SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
        connConfig.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
        try {
            connection.connect();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            connection.login(username, password);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Set the status to available
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        try {
            connection.sendPacket(presence);
        } catch (NotConnectedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static Collection<RosterEntry> getRoster(){
        Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
        Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
        return entries;

    }

    public static void sendMsg(String jid, String msg_text){

    }
}
```

Full stack trace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NotConnectedException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at ChatServer.create_connection(ChatServer.java:73)
    at ChatServer.doPost(ChatServer.java:52)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace? Which line of code is line 75?

Comment: @Freiheit sorry i mean 42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the JAR which contains the `org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException` class. You need to place that JAR on your classpath. Since this appears to be a servlet running in Tomcat you should package that JAR with your application before deploying it.